# Raspbian: USB drive mounted and accessible but doesn't show on `df -h`

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, df

I have an USB drive connected to my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. The directories on it are accessible using `cd`, `ls` etc. but the drive doesn't show up when running `df`. It however does show when I run

```
sudo du -sh /mnt/SYNC
```

`df` with various options doesn't show the drive at all.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: MariusMatutiae suggest I looked at the permissions. I can't see what might be wrong, but then again I am rather new to linux. Permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov  7 15:01 SYNC
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root  4096 Nov  5 23:38 mnt
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with permissions

Comment: How does the mount look in: `cat /etc/mtab`, `cat /proc/mounts` and `mount`? Check the permissions of `/etc/mtab` and the file system `/etc` is on (is not it read-only?)

Comment: [Similar problem](http://superuser.com/q/903083/432690).